# ¿Como hacer una petición POST desde diferentes puertos?

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy tratando de hacer una petición POST a un puerto 3000, desde postman me funciona muy bien, pero en el producción me devuelve null,

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'url.com:3000/login',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{"user":"user","password":"user"}',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',

  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
var_dump($response);
die();
```

Creo que es porque estoy en puertos diferentes.

Comment: Algo en los logs de PHP?

Comment: No es muy clara la pregunta... Una peticion post a un puerto 3000 en tu local desde postman si funciona? pero una peticion desde el mismo postman al servidor de produccion en el puerto 3000 no? Podrías aclarar?

Answer (score 0):

Cuando **Angular, Vue , React** o cualquier otro framework de JavaScript hacen **http request** por cualquier método (**POST,GET,PATCH,PUT,DELETE**) siempre hace un pre-fly a **OPTIONS** (una solicitud de prueba) para saber los métodos permitidos en esa dirección.

Para solucionar este problema.

Utiliza este código

```html
#asi evitamos que vue,angular,React y cualquier otro de errores de CORS
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'OPTIONS') {
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, DELETE, PUT, PATCH, OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: token, Content-Type');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000');
    header('Content-Length: 0');
    header('Content-Type: text/plain');
    die(); //termina la solicitud (pre-fly)
}
```